# How can I "inject" the UserId into my model request?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core

My Employee request:

```
namespace API.Requests {
   public class EmployeeRequest {
       public string Name { get; set; }
       ...
   }

   public static class Extensions {
      public static Employee ToEntity(this EmployeeRequest request) => new Employee {
        Name = request.Name,
        //UserId = ...
        ...
      };
}
```

So in my controller I have:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Poststring( [FromForm] EmployeeRequest request )
{
     var employee = request.ToEntity();
     return Ok(employee.UserId);
}
```

So, what I need is that inside the ToEntity function modify the UserId field through the UserManager so that the entity that I get after executing the ToEntity function includes the UserId.

Thank you! :D

Comment: If you had to do it manually, how exactly would you get the UserId from the Name? Is there a database table you can look in?

Comment: Why not inject the `UserManager` in your controller as usual and pass its instance to the extension which takes a `UserManager` type as a parameter? then i assume the `Name` is the user name you can fetch the user and grab the id from it. or you can fetch the current user using the `ClaimsPrincipal` `User`.

Comment: In my Employee model I have a field called UserId, and it is the one that I want to modify within the ToEntity function

Comment: you wanna modify it based on what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So, what I need is that inside the ToEntity function modify the UserId
> field through the UserManager so that the entity that I get after
> executing the ToEntity function includes the UserId.

Just try this code:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
        public HomeController(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Poststring([FromForm] EmployeeRequest request)
        {
            var employee = await request.ToEntity(_userManager, User);
            return Ok(employee.UserId);
        }
    }

   public static class Extensions
    {
        public async static Task<Employee> ToEntity(this EmployeeRequest request,
            UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager, ClaimsPrincipal user) => new Employee
            {
                UserId = (await _userManager.GetUserAsync(user)).Id.ToString(), 
                Name = request.Name,
            };
    }
```